# Find object in array and change its property if I know its other property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've got an array of objects and I need a function that finds object an array by the objects property (`id` in example) and changes its other property (`name` in example). Currently my implementation looks like this:

```
var arrayOfObjects = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Alpha'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Bravo'
}];

var setNameById = function (id, newName) {
    arrayOfObjects.filter(function(obj) {return obj.id === id;}).name = newName;
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects)); // initial array logged
setNameById(2, 'Charlie');
console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects)); // initial array logged
```

I understand that the problem is in changing the object that is returned by filter and not initial one, but I haven't found implementations that give access to initial object in such a situation, is it possible or do I need to rethink the steps that led me to this point.

Comment: var arrayOfObjects = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Alpha'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Bravo'
}];

var setNameById = function (id, newName) {
    arrayOfObjects.filter(function(obj) {return obj.id == id;})[0].name = newName;
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects)); // initial array logged
setNameById(2, 'Charlie');
console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects));

Comment: Array.filter() will return Array which contains element with specified ID at 0th Index. Use [0].name for setting Name for the specified ID.

Comment: your filter comparation is "obj.id = id" and must be "obj.id == id". I tested with this and worked fine: arrayOfObjects.filter(function(obj) {return obj.id = id;})[0].name = newName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead of filter. Filter produce new array.

```
arrayOfObjects.forEach(function(v){
  if (v.id == id) {v.name = newName}
});
```

Comment: Np. I'm glad this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array#forEach` over `Array#filter`

Note that `==` or `===` should be used to compare, `=` will assign the value!

`Array#forEach` with condition should be enough just to update existing array of object.

```js
var arrayOfObjects = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Alpha'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Bravo'
}];

var setNameById = function(id, newName) {
  var filtered = arrayOfObjects.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.id == id;
  });
  filtered.forEach(function(el) {
    el.name = newName;
  });
  return filtered;
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects));
var filtered = setNameById(2, 'Charlie');
console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered));
```

**Or** use `Array#map`

```js
var arrayOfObjects = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Alpha'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Bravo'
}];

var setNameById = function(id, newName) {
  return arrayOfObjects.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.id == id;
  }).map(function(el) {
    el.name = newName;
    return el;
  });
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects));
var filtered = setNameById(2, 'Charlie');
console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered));
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter returns an array. So will have to use `index` in your approach.

#### Your Approach

```js
var arrayOfObjects = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Alpha'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Bravo'
}];

var setNameById = function(id, newName) {
  arrayOfObjects.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.id = id;
  })[0].name = newName;
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects)); // initial array logged
setNameById(2, 'Charlie');
console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects));
```

#### array.find

If you are sure it will return only one value, use `array.find`

```js
var arrayOfObjects = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Alpha'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Bravo'
}];

var setNameById = function(id, newName) {
  arrayOfObjects.find(function(obj) {
    return obj.id = id;
  }).name = newName;
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects)); // initial array logged
setNameById(2, 'Charlie');
console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects));
```

#### array.forEach

If there can be more than 1 object with same search key (id in this case), use `array.forEach` instead of `array.filter` and then loop over filtered array

```js
var arrayOfObjects = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Alpha'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Bravo'
}];

var setNameById = function(id, newName) {
  arrayOfObjects.forEach(function(obj) {
    if(obj.id = id) obj.name = newName;
  });
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects)); // initial array logged
setNameById(2, 'Charlie');
console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects));
```