# Using $.inArray() for objects inside an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I have an array called: "`additions_colorizing_items`". It has objects inside it, as seen below:

```
    var additions_colorizing_items = [
    '',
    {
        "name": 'viking_helmet',
        "actual_name": 'Viking Helmet',
        "rows": 4,
        "first_color": '#ED2C2B',
        "started_color": 4,
        "type": 'H',
        "type_in_words": 'head',
        "have_shadow_now": 'always',
        'need_shadow': false
    },
    {
        "name": 'hard_hat',
        "actual_name": 'Hard Hat',
        "rows": 4,
        "first_color": 1,
        "started_color": '#F6EB56',
        "type": 'H',
        "type_in_words": '',
        "have_shadow_now": 'always',
        'need_shadow': false
    }, ....]
```

The problem is that `$.inArray` function doesn't work in this case:

```
this_id = 'viking_helmet';
alert(additions_colorizing_items[$.inArray(this_id, additions_colorizing_items.name)].actual_name);
```

The goal is: turning `name` to `actual_name` from the same object inside the array for example: `viking_helmet` -> `Viking Helmet`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please [**search thoroughly**](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+find+object+in+array+by+property) before posting. More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: thank you! I created this account just for this one simple question. I'd like to know if it's possible to do it, and if so how?

Comment: Anyways, I did enough searching in the interenet and didnt find an answer to my question.

Comment: oh my gosh you can't do this to me! This isn't a duplicate and the thing you've doesn't work propely for me! :L

Comment: Maybe better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758937/using-jquery-inarray-with-array-of-javascript-objects   So, using of grep can help, and commented is one of possible vanilla js solutions: https://jsfiddle.net/c1roky6e/ P.S. If i understand your requirement correctly...:)

Comment: I'm using jQuery and I just want to switch a value in an object to another value in the same object.

Comment: Did you checked jsfiddle? If it doesn't help, you will need to explain better what is expected result...

Comment: btw thanks for helping me! I searched sometime before about jQuery.grep() and i'm not intersted removing parts of my object if I understand it correctly. The expected result is another  value from the same object - but by another variable. For example: if I have the value of 'name' that I got from an id. I want a function that will give me the value of 'actual_name' from the same object 'name' comes from inside the big array.

Comment: Hey! If you don't mind. I'd like to get some help if you know how to solve my issue either tell me what can I do with the possible "duplicates"

Comment: If the primary goal is changing `name` to `actual_name` where `name === this_id`, [it's covered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872923/find-object-in-array-and-change-its-property-if-i-know-its-other-property) (I've added it at the top of the list above).